# "status_code": 422, "error_code": "REQUEST_PARAM_PARSE", "detail": "The 'data' parameter must be a list"

Tags: json, monkeylearn

I’m using the HTTP Request Wizard to set up a POST request to MonkeyLearn. This endpoint expects a JSON in the request body (or payload body). It must be an object with the data property and a list of the texts you want to classify as value. For example:

```
{
  "data": [
    "This is the best sentiment analysis tool ever!!!",
  ]
}
```

So, in the HTTP Request Wizard, I set up under Parameters:
Name: data
Value: "This is the best sentiment analysis tool evert!!!"
Type: GetorPost

However, in the preview response I get:

```
{
  "status_code": 422,
  "error_code": "REQUEST_PARAM_PARSE",
  "detail": "The ‘data’ parameter must be a list"
}
```

I can’t figure out what list the endpoint expect?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the "HTTP Request Wizard" and cannot find it either. But from what you've written it is clear that you are sending a string and not an array of strings. You value should look like this: `Value: [ "This is the best sentiment analysis tool evert!!!" ]`